# What does "DEL:" mean in the DistinguishedName of an AD Object?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, domain-controller

Sorry -- I'm not really a Windows System Admin, just trying to slam through some LDAP interactions in Java.

I'm finding a ton of objects with "DEL:" in the distinguishedName.  Are these orphaned items that are awaiting garbage collection?  How do I remove them?  I can't really find them through ADUC, but I can find them via Java LDAP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are deleted objects. The process happens when an object is deleted so that other domain controllers can be made aware of the deletion. This is [documented in great detail on TechNet.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258310)

Don't delete these, write your program to not return them as results. Excluding `CN=Deleted Objects, DC=Domain, DC=tld` from your queries should be enough, as this is where they're all put.

Comment: I wish I had enough Karma here to upvote you or accept this as an answer -- Thanks for the super speedy response! :)

Comment: @RichieForeman You can accept an answer regardless of your rep. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) -- you need to wait at least 15 minutes before you can accept.